# Xcode iOS Generate .png file and save it using NSFileManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I am making an iOS app and I got a UIImage - I want to compress it into .png file and save it to the app's documents folder - I already have the path and all I need is how to convert the UIImage to .png and save it.

Thanks,
Matan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

so the code is:

```
UIImage *yourImage = ...; //the image you have
NSString *targetPath = ...; // something like ~/Library/Documents/myImage.png

[UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage) writeToFile:targetPath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: is there any method to compress png?

Comment: no. you could include the pngcrush sources. but there is nothing in the frameworks

Answer (score 3):

For PNG:

```
UIImagePNGRepresentation
```

Returns the data for the specified image in PNG format

```
NSData * UIImagePNGRepresentation (
   UIImage *image
);
```

---

If you wanted JPEG instead:

```
UIImageJPEGRepresentation
```

Returns the data for the specified image in JPEG format.

```
NSData * UIImageJPEGRepresentation (
   UIImage *image,
   CGFloat compressionQuality
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Image compression form is JPEG you can use different quality of jpg image

```
// for getting png image
 NSData*theImageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(theImage);
// for JPG compression change fill value between less than 1 
 NSData*theImageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(theImage, 1);
// for converting raw data image to UIImage
 UIImage *imageOrignal=[UIImage imageWithData:theImageData];
// for saving in to photos gallery
 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageOrignal,nil,nil,nil);
```